# Expect jest mock to have been called with an argument fails in react testing library

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

I would expect this test to pass but it fails:

```
it('should consume files on drop', () => {
  const mock = jest.fn();
  const file = new File(['file'], 'file.txt', { type: 'text/plain' });
  const fileList = [file];

  render(<DropZone onDocumentDrop={mock} />);

  const dropZone = screen.getByTestId('dropZone');
  const dropEvent = createEvent.drop(dropZone);

  Object.defineProperty(dropEvent, 'dataTransfer', {
    value: {
      files: {
        item: (index: number) => fileList[index],
        length: fileList.length,
      },
    },
  });

  fireEvent(dropZone, dropEvent);

  expect(dropZone).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    item: (index: number) => fileList[index],
    length: 1,
  });
});
```

Jest reports that:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

- Expected
+ Received

- {"item": [Function item], "length": 1},
+ {"item": [Function item], "length": 1},
```

I am not sure how to make it pass or get anymore insight into what is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When checking the arguments of the last function call, you can use [`expect.objectContaining()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectobjectcontainingobject) to match the received object.

You can also use `lastCalledWith()` instead of `toHaveBeenCalledWith()`. They are both the same but I personally prefer the former because it's shorter and easier to read.

```js
const item = (index: number) => []
const args = {
  length: 1,
  item,
}

const mock = jest.fn()

mock(args)

expect(mock).lastCalledWith(
  expect.objectContaining({
    length: expect.any(Number), // or 1 if you know the exact value
    item: expect.any(Function),
  })
)
```

Comment: As a side note, you can actually nest expect.objectContaining. Comes in handy when testing network responses. E.g `expect.objectContaining(status:"fullfilled", body:expect.objectContaining({id:"1"}))`

Answer (score 1):

Two different objects in javascript are not the same value, even if they have the same key/value pairs - An object is stored in memory as a reference and so two different objects have two different references, therefore they are not equal.

Try defining the object once instead and passing it's reference around:

```
const files = {
    item: (index: number) => fileList[index],
    length: fileList.length,
};

Object.defineProperty(dropEvent, 'dataTransfer', { value: { files, }, });
// -- snip --- //
expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(files);
```